# JBOSS 6.2 EAP not starting in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have added Jboss 6.2 EAP in my eclipse toolkit and I am trying to start it in normal mode. But the server does not start at all and I dont see any errors in the console or in server.log or in boot.log.

I am using JDK 1.7 and JBOSS 7.2.1. I have added the entry for environment variables

Could you please help me resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried starting it from the console using standalone file?

Comment: Are you using jboss tools? you need an updated version see this https://developer.jboss.org/thread/237040